# Geotools MultiPolygon to DB and back

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, geotools

I am reading a set of data containing a large number of multypoligons. I am using the Geotools and I would like to store this list in a mysql database table.

I don't know how to store the shape in an efficient way and be able to recreate a multipolygon object.

If I get the coordinates of the multipolygon, then I get an array containing the values of all the vertices for this geometry (In the case the geometry is a composite, the array contains all the vertices for the components, in the order in which the components occur in the geometry), but I don't know how to recreate a new multipolygon with those coordinates.

Please find below what I got at.

```
private List<Shape> parseFile2ShapeList(File file) {

    List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    FileDataStore myData = null;
    SimpleFeatureIterator sfit = null;
    try {
        // Extract all features
        myData = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore( file );
        SimpleFeatureSource source = myData.getFeatureSource();
        SimpleFeatureCollection sfc = source.getFeatures();
        sfit = sfc.features();

        // Read the features and store in a list only the ones with Venue_ID
        while (sfit.hasNext()) {
            SimpleFeature feature = sfit.next();
            String id = (String) feature.getAttribute("ID");
            MultiPolygon mulPoly = (MultiPolygon) feature.getAttribute("the_geom");
            Shape shape = new Shape(id, mulPoly);
            shapes.add(shape);
        }  
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sfit.close();
        myData.dispose();
    }
    return shapes;
}

private boolean insertShapes(List<Shape> shapes) {
    // Insert the shapes in the DB
    boolean inserted = false;
    try (Database db = new Database()) {
        // Store in the DB all the shapes
        for (Shape shape : shapes) {
            db.getShapesDao().insertShape(shape); // What shall I store in the DB if the shape is a multipolygon? What if it is any Geometry?
        }   
        inserted = true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        inserted = false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        inserted = false;
    }
    return inserted;
}

private Shape selectShape(String shape_id) {
    Shape shape = null;
    try (Database db = new Database()) {
        // Retrieve the shape
        shape = db.getShapesDao().getShapeById(shape_id); // How do I recreate a multipolygon (or any other Geometry inserted in the DB?)
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return shape;
}

public void main() {

    // display a data store file chooser dialog for shapefiles
    File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("shp", null);
    if (file == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Read the file and load in memory the venues
    List<Shape> shapes = parseFile2ShapeList(file);
    System.out.println("Shapes parsed: " + retrieved.size());
    for (Shape shape : shapes) {
        System.out.println("\t ID: " + shape.getId() ); 
    }

    // Insert in database
    boolean inserted = insertVenues(venues);
    System.out.println("Insertion successful? " + inserted);

    // Retrieve from database
    List<Shape> retrievedShapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    for (Shape shape : shapes) {
        Shape retrieved = selectShape(shape.getId());
        retrievedShapes.add(retrieved);
    }
    System.out.println("Shapes retrieved: " + retrieved.size());
    for (Shape shape : retrievedShapes) {
        System.out.println("\t ID: " + shape.getId() ); 
    }
}
```

At the moment from a multipolygon I know how to get a polygon back (because I simply store the coordinates and I use them to create a polygon), but I don't know what to do to store and retrieve a multipolygon.
In general, the optimal solution would work for any Geometry:

> parse geometry obj -> store geometry to DB (with associated ID) -> (some time later...) -> retrieve geometry information (by ID) -> construct new geometry obj

The new object will be a copy of the original one, which is not available anymore.

PS: Serialising a Java object and store it in the DB is something that I would not want to do as I would like to have in the DB something somehow human readable. :)

---- edit

I am adding more information following the answer I received (thank you @user2731872!).

The database table I would like to store things in has the following schema:

```
mysql> describe shape_table;
+-----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| shape_id        | varchar(32)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| shape           | text                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

There are other columns to this table, but for the moment they are not relevant. In any case, given the input file, I would like to store every geometry (`shape` column) in a different row.

In my program, given a `shape_id` I would like to retrieve the associated information about the shape (`shape` column) and then construct the geometry.

Answer (score 1):

You are working at too low a level and thus are making it hard on yourself. GeoTools is designed (for most users/uses) to work with DataStores which abstract the details away and features which handle geometry and attributes for you. So your problem breaks in to two parts - 1st read in the shapefile and 2nd write the features to the database. You have succeeded with the first step, the second is a bit trickier but fairly easy.

Get a connection to the DB (I've used PostGIS as I have it installed but MySql should work the same way):

```
params.put("user", "geotools");
params.put("passwd", "geotools");
params.put("port", "5432");
params.put("host", "127.0.0.1");
params.put("database", "geotools");
params.put("dbtype", "postgis");
dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
```

Then send the features to the dataSource:

```
SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = dataStore
.getFeatureSource(schema.getName().getLocalPart());
if (featureSource instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
    SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;
    featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
    try {
        List < FeatureId > ids = featureStore.addFeatures(features);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception problem) {
        problem.printStackTrace();
        transaction.rollback();
    } finally {
        transaction.close();
    }
    dataStore.dispose();
    return true;
} else {
    dataStore.dispose();
    System.err.println("Database not writable");
    return false;
}
```

There is a bit of messing about the handle creation of new tables if needed and such like which you can see in the [full code](https://gitlab.com/snippets/5735), which creates a new table if needed or appends to the existing one.

Comment: Thank you ian! I don't like the way the parameters configuration is done in DataStores and I am not sure the code would be easier to read in case I want to save only some specific attributes of the features (I would probably have to filter out the attributes I don't want to store). I just posted an alternative solution but I would be happy to hear from you what you think.

Comment: You can use JNDI if you prefer to handle the connections that way.  The simplest way to choose just some of the attributes is to pass a query in to the shapefile datastore which limits the attributes returned and also allows you to filter the features returned.

Comment: Iant's answer is the way to go. FOr more training ( with a shp data store) look here http://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/feature/csv2shp.html For manipulating the attributes to be stored in a feature, you manipulate the schema (see link provided for how it is created). If you want to subset, look at this: DataUtilties.createSubType(SimpleFeatureType, String[]) in here http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/main/data.html

Answer (score 0):

(not tested) Geotools has an MySQL Data Store:
http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/data/mysql/MySQLDataStoreFactory.html

also documetned here: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jdbc/mysql.html

You should be able to take the FeatureCollection you read from SHP and push it to the new datastore. Thus,

```
SimpleFeatureCollection sfc
```

is what you want to pass to the SimpleFeatureSource source that you define for this datastore. Something like

```
DataUtilities.source( collection );
```

as per the user guide: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/main/collection.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I am looking into it, but I don't seem to find what I need. The DataStore seems more for retrieving information rather than inserting info in a given mysql table. I will edit the question adding more details.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found is to use WKTWriter and WKTReader classes. This is what I wrote in my DAO class:

```
static private String INSERT_SHAPE = "INSERT INTO shape_table(shape_id, shape) VALUES (?, ?)";

static private String GET_SHAPE_BY_ID = "SELECT shape FROM shape_table WHERE shape_id = ?";


public void insertShape(String shape_id, Geometry shape) throws SQLException {
    try (PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SHAPE)) {
        s.setString(1, shape_id);
        WKTWriter writer = new WKTWriter();
        String wkt = writer.write(shape);
        s.setString(2, wkt);
        s.executeUpdate();
    }
}

public Geometry getShapeById(String shape_id) throws SQLException, ParseException {
    String wkt = null;
    Geometry shape = null;
    WKTReader reader = new WKTReader();
    try (PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(GET_SHAPE_BY_ID)) {
        s.setString(1, shape_id);
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            wkt = rs.getString("shape");
            shape = reader.read(wkt);
        }
        return shape;
    }
}
```

This solution satisfies me, as in the DB table I can see the whole geometry and store the rest of the information in a table that is already created in a specific way. Of course I am interested in hearing your comments.

Comment: This will be slower to read/write and prevents the DB indexing the geometry.  It will also prevent you using standard mapping tools on your db.

Comment: This solution basically does not use Geotools. It works with JTS for the Geometry. It is a very low-level solution that would cause problems in production implementations relying on other advanced Geotools use. You also do not manipulate entire features, just the Geometry ( untyped). You may end up mixing Line and Points and Polygons etc... Depending on the backend, this may or may not be possible.

Comment: As the comments above say this solution might not be using the potential of Geotools and it might be "low-level" in that it reads a specific attribute (i.e. _the_geom_) of every feature before inserting . Nevertheless, I tested this solution with a file containing more than 3000 polygons and multipolygons and what I have in the shape file always matched what I retrieved from my mysql table after the insertion. Note, however, that I had to change the table column type from text to **mediumtext**.